# Room Designations and the "Home Sweet Home" Achievement

Tags: achievements, fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter, there is an achievement ("Home Sweet Home") for "Build 1 of every room type". Unfortunately, the game does not provide any more details about what is required.

What I have noticed is that any particular room type actually has 3 different names, depending on its upgrade level (e.g., a level 1 Living Quarters is a "Living Quarters", level 2 is a "Residence" and level 3 are "Barracks").  However, *merging* rooms (so a 1 or 2 wide vs a 3 wide) does not have this effect.

I've unlocked and built almost all the room types (except for the Nuka Cola production centre), but my percent for this achievement is only 20%.

Can anyone confirm that this achievement requires 3 of each room type to be built simultaneously, each with a different level of upgrade?  Or if I only have 1 of each room type built and upgrade each to level 3, should this suffice? (since all levels 3s were level 1/2 beforehand)

EDIT: I have put [together a spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ugt9qbhId9r1WYyTWUl3z667Yey9YUaGMABvU69nmm0/edit?usp=sharing) to track my progress.  Interestingly, according to my calculations, I should be at 35% complete - but Game Center still says 20.  I don't know all of the names yet, please comment if you have any I don't!

Answer (score 3):

INTERIM ANSWER:

I have been working on this problem since I started playing the game, and have come to an odd conclusion: "room types" might include having a full room (3 units) of each type.

I have tracked my Vault's progress on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ugt9qbhId9r1WYyTWUl3z667Yey9YUaGMABvU69nmm0/), and have clearly indicated:

- The 19 types of rooms, and their 3 subtypes

  - e.g., the 3 levels for Diner are: Diner, Restaurant, Cafeteria.
- The number of each rooms I currently have in my vault.
- If 1 or more are present, a 1 gets placed in the "Present" column.
- This column is summed and divided by 57 (3 room types times 19 rooms), and presented as a percentage.

I honestly thought that once I had one of each of the room types, the achievement would unlock.  However, this was **not** the case.  At my current loadout, Game Center reports that I am only 40% complete for the achievement.

This has me thinking that not only do we require 1 of each room type, but they all must be of size 3 (many of my level 3 rooms are only size 1).  I have now started tracking the sizes of my rooms.  My next step is to get a size 3, level 3 of each room type and see how that affects the percentage.

Comment: I built up a vault essentially maxed out dwellers, all types built and maxed out at size 3, I'm stuck at 98%. I think the game is just not tracking this well. It seems to have skipped counting one. I even demolished a fair amount of my vault to built all at each level and size, no change.

Comment: I would love to hear if you ever found a solution for this. I'm currently stumped on the achievement as well.

Answer (score 3):

I was also confused from this one achievement, having all rooms 3 squares long and upgraded. Then I stumbled on this [post](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1535610-home-sweet-home-achievement/#entry24317720), basically stating you need 1-wide, un-merged, un-upgraded rooms of each kind.

After building of 1 square room of each kind and not upgrading them, the achievement unlocked on my vault.